# Event onblur not working in <input> element | JS

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new on JS and I need to call an external function when an onblur event happens with the `<input type="text" id="username">`.

Here is the code:

```
<input type="text" id="username">
<input type="hidden" id="feedback" value="">

<script>

    var elUsername = document.getElementById("username");

    elUsername.onblur = PagSeguroDirectPayment.onSenderHashReady(function(response){
        if(response.status == 'error') {
            console.log(response.message);
            return false;
        }
        var hash = response.senderHash; //Hash will be available here.

        var elFeedback = document.getElementById("feedback");
        elFeedback.setAttribute("value", hash);
    });

</script>
```

The code shows no error but as soon as the page loads, the function is being called, sending the `hash` value immediately to the `<input type="text" id="username"`>. Instead of this, I'd like that this value was only available as the onblur event had been triggered.

Thank you!

Comment: onblur expects a reference to a function which it can execute when the blur occurs. You're instead executing the function and assigning `onblur` the return value or your `onSenderHasRead()` method

Comment: Hi, Nick! Is there a way to fix that and execute the function only when onblur happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onblur` event handler expects a reference to a function which it can execute when the blur occurs. You're instead executing the function and then assigning onblur the return value of your `onSenderHasRead()` method.

As stated above, `onblur` expects a reference to a function. In order to do this, you can write your own function which performs the code you want to run when the blur occurs. Then, you can assign `onblur` a reference to this function:

```
function handleBlur() {
  PagSeguroDirectPayment.onSenderHashReady(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'error') {
      console.log(response.message);
      return false;
    }
    var hash = response.senderHash; //Hash will be available here.

    var elFeedback = document.getElementById("feedback");
    elFeedback.setAttribute("value", hash);
  });
}

elUsername.onblur = handleBlur; // a reference to the handleBlur function (note: we are not calling this function, as onblur will call it for us)
```

Having to create an additional function and then using it later on can disrupt the flow of your code sometimes, so you'll often see people use an [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_function_expression), which are function expressions that can be assigned in-line, and don't require a name (hence the anonymity):

```
// onblur will call this --\/ function when a blur occurs
elUsername.onblur = function() {
  PagSeguroDirectPayment.onSenderHashReady(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'error') {
      console.log(response.message);
      return false;
    }
    var hash = response.senderHash; //Hash will be available here.

    var elFeedback = document.getElementById("feedback");
    elFeedback.setAttribute("value", hash);
  });
}
```

These days it's often good practice to use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than modifying the element's blur event handler. This way if another library or piece of code overwrites the `onblur` property later on, your `blur` event will still be registered:

```
elUsername.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  PagSeguroDirectPayment.onSenderHashReady(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'error') {
      console.log(response.message);
      return false;
    }
    var hash = response.senderHash; //Hash will be available here.

    var elFeedback = document.getElementById("feedback");
    elFeedback.setAttribute("value", hash);
  });
});
```